# How to know the progress of buffered data in html5 audio?

Tags: html5-audio

Using html5 audio tags with Ogg media files, how can I using javascript, retrieve how much data has been loaded on the client side (in realtime).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
<audio id="warp" preload="auto" controls>
    <source src="warp.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    <source src="warp.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
<script>
    var a = document.getElementById('warp');
    var t = a.currentTime;
    var d = a.duration;
    var z = a.buffered.end(a.buffered.length-1);
</script>
```

z is the number of seconds of audio that is currently buffered. 
t is the number of seconds from the beginning of the audio track where the playhead is.
d is the total number of seconds of the audio track.

Comment: in 2020 it will cause an error: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'end' on 'TimeRanges': The index provided (4294967295) is greater than the maximum bound (0).